# eliminating words until the result is defined

Tags: r, for-loop, geolocation, ggmap

I'm currently making code returning the lat and long of the address by using geocode.

```
library(ggmap)

name <- "720-37, Chorok-ro, Yanggam-myeon, Hwaseong-si, Gyeonggi-do, Republic of Korea"
address <- geocode(name)
df <- data.frame(lat = as.numeric(address[2]), lon = as.numeric(address[1]))
```

if the address in the name sentence have no result in google, it automatically returns NA for lat an long.

Therefore how can I keep eliminating the words until there is a result (Usually, if the address is too specified, there is no result). In this case, if "720-37, chorok-ro" is eliminated, it works.

Comment: Are you using the `geocdoe` function from the `ggmap` package?

Comment: When I used `geocode` from the `ggmap` package on the address your provided, it works fine. The result is `lon: 126.9827, lat: 37.11354`.

Comment: Okay but in other case, the case that I need to delete some front words to be run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I can use the `geocode` function from the [ggmap](/questions/tagged/ggmap) package to geocode the address you provided, so it is not a good test case. I thus changed your test case by adding two new words in the beginning.

```
# Test case
name <- "Alpha, Beta, 720-37, Chorok-ro, Yanggam-myeon, Hwaseong-si, Gyeonggi-do, Republic of Korea"
```

Here I showed that the standard `geocode` function will not work.

```
library(ggmap)
geocode(name)
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Alpha,%20Beta,%20720-37,%20Chorok-ro,%20Yanggam-myeon,%20Hwaseong-si,%20Gyeonggi-do,%20Republic%20of%20Korea&sensor=false
  lon lat
1  NA  NA
Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "Alpha, Beta, 720-37, Chorok-ro, Yanggam-myeon, Hwaseong-si, Gyeonggi-do, Republic of Korea"
```

And then I designed a function to conduct "stepwise" geocode, which uses a while-loop to check if there are results. If not, remove the first word and then try again until there are results.

```
# A function to perform the geocode by step-wise eliminating the word from the top
geocode_step <- function(name){
  # Perform geocode
  coords <- geocode(name)
  # Use while loop to check the result, if both lat and lon are NA
  # Remove the first word and then try again
  while (is.na(coords[[1]]) & is.na(coords[[2]])){
    name_vec <- strsplit(name, split = ",")[[1]][-1]
    # All words are eliminated, stop the function and return a data frame with NA and warning
    if (length(name_vec) == 0){
      break
    }
    # Re-combine all words
    name <- paste(name_vec, collapse = ", ")
    # Conduct geocode again
    coords <- geocode(name)
  }
  dat <- data.frame(lon = coords[[1]], lat = coords[[2]], name = name)
  return(dat)
}
```

We can test the function as follows.

```
geocode_step(name)
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Alpha,%20Beta,%20720-37,%20Chorok-ro,%20Yanggam-myeon,%20Hwaseong-si,%20Gyeonggi-do,%20Republic%20of%20Korea&sensor=false
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%20Beta,%20%20720-37,%20%20Chorok-ro,%20%20Yanggam-myeon,%20%20Hwaseong-si,%20%20Gyeonggi-do,%20%20Republic%20of%20Korea&sensor=false
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%20%20720-37,%20%20%20Chorok-ro,%20%20%20Yanggam-myeon,%20%20%20Hwaseong-si,%20%20%20Gyeonggi-do,%20%20%20Republic%20of%20Korea&sensor=false
       lon      lat
1 126.9827 37.11354
                                                                                       name
1   720-37,   Chorok-ro,   Yanggam-myeon,   Hwaseong-si,   Gyeonggi-do,   Republic of Korea
Warning messages:
1: geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "Alpha, Beta, 720-37, Chorok-ro, Yanggam-myeon, Hwaseong-si, Gyeonggi-do, Republic of Korea" 
2: geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = " Beta,  720-37,  Chorok-ro,  Yanggam-myeon,  Hwaseong-si,  Gyeonggi-do,  Republic of Korea"
```

Finaly, if there are no any words will work, the function will still return a data frame with `NA`.

```
geocode_step("aawsd")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=aawsd&sensor=false
  lon lat  name
1  NA  NA aawsd
Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "aawsd"
```

Comment: really appreciate for your help, this is just perfect

Comment: can I ask you one more question, if there is a result with an address, how can we distinguish the city and province. Normally if is not my country it is hard to know which part is city or province

Comment: @Arvin This is an interesting question but probably not related to programming. I have no ideas. I can only imagine that if there is a database storing the name of cities and province, we will be able to search the location name on that database. It may be worthy of searching if such database exists.